# Flutter custom class containing array

Tags: arrays, class, flutter

This should be an easy one for you blokes.

I have a class, like so:

```
class MenuItem {

  final String uid;
  final String category;

  MenuItem ({ this.uid, this.category });

}

class ItemData {

  final String URL;
  final String itemName;
  final String itemDescription;
  final double itemPrice;

  ItemData({ this.URL, this.itemName, this.itemDescription, this.itemPrice });

}
```

I need to have an array in this class, of Strings so you can add tags such as "vegan", "gluten free", "contains nuts"... that kind of thing.   Not sure how to actually implement this in the class.   Is it like:

```
class MenuItem {

  final String uid;
  final String category;

  MenuItem ({ this.uid, this.category });

}

class ItemData {

  final String URL;
  final String itemName;
  final String itemDescription;
  final tags = [];      // An attempt has been made.
  final double itemPrice;

  ItemData({ this.URL, this.itemName, this.itemDescription, this.tags[], this.itemPrice });

}
```

Cos that doesn't really work.

Comment: Someone just posted what appeared to be a really good answer and then deleted it before I could accept.   If you put it back I will accept it, otherwise I will update this question myself with what the user posted later.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the "List" type: `List<String>` to declare a collection (list in this case).

Then you can create it with the `[]` syntax.

Take a look at [Dart's List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/List-class.html) documentation.

#### Update:

the deleted answer (which I just saw) appears to be correct... not sure why the OP deleted it /shrugh

Answer (score 0):

I think i can answer this. This answer is for you if you want to select any one of "vegan", "gluten free", "contains nuts"... etc, you will have to search for another method if you want to select multiple options at a time.

Have a static variable instead of a list.

```
static const int vegan = 0;
static const int glutterFree = 1;
static const int containsNuts = 2;
final int tag;
```

and create the constructor like this:

```
ItemData({ this.URL, this.itemName, this.itemDescription, this.tag, this.itemPrice });
```

You can pass the parameter like this now:

```
ItemData _itemData = ItemData(tag: ItemData.vegan, /*other parameters*/);
```

Hope this meets your requirement. If not please mention me in the comment. Happy coding:)